# apply a show on hover to a repeating div that changes name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Ok I have a div that I increment the name by one on every loop.  There could be an infinate number of divs as they are part of a news loop

```
   <?php $i=1; do {?>
 <div id="linkdiv<?php echo $i;?>">
     <div id="divTwo<?php echo $i;?>" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>
   </div>
  <?php } while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_query)); ?>
```

both divs have a statement to increment the number by one every loop.  Works fine!  Now I have a function in the header which when you hover over linkdiv it displays divTwo.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#linkdiv').hover(function() { 
    $('#divTwo').show(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#divTwo').hide(); 
});
});
</script>
```

It is possible to adapt this function to work with what I have got?  I have tried moving the function inside my loop but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: try using classes instead of IDs

Comment: If you have linkdiv id in the parent element, the child elements normally do not need another (but same numbered) id any longer. That's superfluous, keep your markup clean.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`starts with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector. Try the following:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
$('div[id^=linkdiv]').hover(function() { 
    $(this).find('div').show(); 
}, function() { 
    $(this).find('div').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Ok @raminson i implemented this code but still nothing. Am I supposed to change the 'div' to divTwo?  I have edited the post above to include my loop to make it easier to see what im doing thanks

Comment: @DanielRobinson no, this should work, there is no need to do so, are you sure jQuery is loaded correctly?

Comment: yes im pretty sure.  Im using googles jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

`ids` need to be explicitly different within a page...for same use `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('div[id^="linkdiv"]').hover(function() { 
         $(this).next().show(); 
       }, function() { 
         $('this').next().hide(); 
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to give a class to all your divs

```
<div class="linkdiv" id="linkdiv23">...</div>
```

Now you don't need to use any trickery -

```
$('div.linkdiv').hover(function() { 
    $(this).find('div').show(); 
}, function() { 
    $(this).find('div').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

made changes to markup, more simple and more options with jquery, you can target all with `.linkdiv` or specific with `.linkdiv-X`, same applies to `.divTwo`

```
  <?php $i=1; do {?>
 <div class="linkdiv linkdiv-<?php echo $i;?>">
     <div class="divTwo divTwo-<?php echo $i;?>" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>
   </div>
  <?php } while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_query)); ?>
```

this should generate something like

```
 <div class="linkdiv linkdiv-X">
     <div class="divTwo divTwo-X" style="display: none;"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>
   </div>
```

and jquery for that

```
$(".linkdiv").hover(function(){
 $(this).find(".divTwo").show();
},function(){
 $(this).find(".divTwo").hide();
});
```